Why does App Check with Play Integrity not work?
I have a problem implementing App Check with Play Integrity into my Flutter App. I have followed the documentation and searched the internet for 3 days but couldn't find any solution.
Even after opening the app after download from Google Play Store and activating App Check in the Code, I still got 100% unverified requests in the App Check console. I have no idea why my app isn't recognised by App Check. Also in the Play Integrity Tab in the Google Play Console (after selecting my GC Project) it says "ready for Integration", although I have already done it.
Why is my app not sending verified requests? What steps am I missing?
• I put the sha256 key from Google Play Store App Signature to firebase app check
• Play Integrity API is activated & my Firebase project is linked to the Google Play Console / Play Integrity API
• I have added the App Check sdk & activated it in the code.
• I registered my debug tokens in the Firebase Console, but App Check didn't work with the Debug Provider either.
• I have downloaded and set up the latest google-services.json file from the Firebase Console
• I published a new build to the Play Store and downloaded it, but App Check didn't work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
